# Sort Mixed Element thruple in Python - KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Say I have a thruple list:

```
data = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 2},
]
```

How would I sort it on the second element `b`? So that the sorted list would look like:

```
data = [
    {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 2},
]
```

I've tried `sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1))` and `sorted(data, key=lambda test: test[1])`, however I am getting a `KeyError: 1`.

As my list involves a letter and a number, I am unsure on how to proceed to solve this. I don't want to convert it to a string as i'll have to access the numbers later. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sorted(data,key=itemgetter('b'))`

Comment: `sorted(data,key=lambda test:test['b'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(dic):
    return dic["b"]

print (sorted(data,key=func))
```

This returns the output you expect